# How to filter on-click in react three js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

So I explore [2 cubes sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-demo-forked-9h1xg). I want to click only on one cube at a time. Yet when I click on a cube that has a cube right behind the current one both get clicked. How to force click and hover only on the nearest one?

In other words clicking\hovering on cube A I want cube B not to be clicked
[image]

My code sample:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { Canvas, useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber'

function Box(props) {
  // This reference will give us direct access to the mesh
  const mesh = useRef()
  // Set up state for the hovered and active state
  const [hovered, setHover] = useState(false)
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
  // Rotate mesh every frame, this is outside of React without overhead
  useFrame(() => {
    mesh.current.rotation.x = mesh.current.rotation.y += 0.01
  })
  return (
    <mesh
      {...props}
      ref={mesh}
      scale={active ? 1.5 : 1}
      onClick={(e) => setActive(!active)}
      onPointerOver={(e) => setHover(true)}
      onPointerOut={(e) => setHover(false)}>
      <boxGeometry args={[1, 1, 1]} />
      <meshStandardMaterial color={hovered ? 'hotpink' : 'orange'} />
    </mesh>
  )
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <spotLight position={[10, 10, 10]} angle={0.15} penumbra={1} />
      <pointLight position={[-10, -10, -10]} />
      <Box position={[1.2, 0.5, 0]} />
      <Box position={[1.2, 0, 0]} />
    </Canvas>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are your both cubes defined in one geometry?

Comment: It would be helpful to share some code

Comment: @AbdullahKhan: added code sample

Comment: I tested your code, the default behavior seems reasonable, the only region where both boxes are being highlighted simultaneously if you hover over the intersected region. However, if you were to hover on any other region it seems to highlight that cube

Comment: Not sure what your requirements are, but perhaps you would like to bring those cubes apart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-demo-forked-v8ji5)

main diff:

```
function intersectionsFilter(intersections) {
  return intersections?.length ? [intersections[0]] : intersections
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas raycaster={{ filter: intersectionsFilter }}>
```

Comment: if using events with react you can also use e.stopPropagation();